# Why is this script only working once? Replaces element only once, then never again

Tags: javascript

I've got a puzzle here and this may just be a limitation of JS but here's the code and it works ONCE. Then... never again. Not sure why.

It basically is replacing the TD content with code set up in each JS call. The initial table is setup to just open a stream channel from a device at an IP through the VLC plug in. When the page loads, the default code runs fine in the table.

Then when I click a button, it swaps out the proper code, the new stream fires off and then it never works again :(...

Doesn't seem like anything amazingly hard to process yet, I'm apparently missing something or perhaps some knowledge of limitations?

Thanks for any insight.

> Blockquote

```
<table><tr><td id="TABLENAME">
<embed pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org"
            type="application/x-vlc-plugin"
            version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2"
            id="srcVIDEO4"
            width="324"
            height="132"
            autoplay="yes" loop="no"
            target="rtsp://192.168.88.235:556/stream.sdp" />
</td></tr></table>

<script>
function display556VIDEO4(){
    var strVIDEO4 = '<embed pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org" \
            type="application\/x-vlc-plugin" \
            version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2" \
            id="srcVIDEO4" \
            width="324" \
            height="132" \
            autoplay="yes" loop="no" \
            target="rtsp://192.168.88.235:556/stream.sdp" />';

    var tdElementVIDEO4 = document.getElementById('TABLENAME');
    var trElementVIDEO4 = tdElementVIDEO4.parentNode;
    trElementVIDEO4.removeChild(tdElementVIDEO4);
    trElementVIDEO4.innerHTML = strVIDEO4 + trElementVIDEO4.innerHTML;
}

function display557VIDEO4(){
    var strVIDEO4 = '<embed pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org" \
            type="application\/x-vlc-plugin" \
            version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2" \
            id="srcVIDEO4" \
            width="324" \
            height="132" \
            autoplay="yes" loop="no" \
            target="rtsp://192.168.88.235:557/stream.sdp" />';
    var tdElementVIDEO4 = document.getElementById('TABLENAME');
    var trElementVIDEO4 = tdElementVIDEO4.parentNode;
    trElementVIDEO4.removeChild(tdElementVIDEO4);
    trElementVIDEO4.innerHTML = strVIDEO4 + trElementVIDEO4.innerHTML;
}

function display558VIDEO4(){
    var strVIDEO4 = '<embed pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org" \
            type="application\/x-vlc-plugin" \
            version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2" \
            id="srcVIDEO4" \
            width="324" \
            height="132" \
            autoplay="yes" loop="no" \
            target="rtsp://192.168.88.235:558/stream.sdp" />';
    var tdElementVIDEO4 = document.getElementById('TABLENAME');
    var trElementVIDEO4 = tdElementVIDEO4.parentNode;
    trElementVIDEO4.removeChild(tdElementVIDEO4);
    trElementVIDEO4.innerHTML = strVIDEO4 + trElementVIDEO4.innerHTML;
}

function display559VIDEO4(){
    var strVIDEO4 = '<embed pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org" \
            type="application\/x-vlc-plugin" \
            version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2" \
            id="srcVIDEO4" \
            width="324" \
            height="132" \
            autoplay="yes" loop="no" \
            target="rtsp://192.168.88.235:559/stream.sdp" />';
    var tdElementVIDEO4 = document.getElementById('TABLENAME');
    var trElementVIDEO4 = tdElementVIDEO4.parentNode;
    trElementVIDEO4.removeChild(tdElementVIDEO4);
    trElementVIDEO4.innerHTML = strVIDEO4 + trElementVIDEO4.innerHTML;
}

</script>
<button style="background-color:green" type="button" onclick="display556VIDEO4()">6</button>-
<button style="background-color:green" type="button" onclick="display557VIDEO4()">7</button>-
<button style="background-color:green" type="button" onclick="display558VIDEO4()">8</button>-
<button style="background-color:green" type="button" onclick="display559VIDEO4()">9</button><br/>
```

> Blockquote

Answer (score 2):

```
function display558VIDEO4(){
    var strVIDEO4 = '<embed pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org" \
            type="application\/x-vlc-plugin" \
            version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2" \
            id="srcVIDEO4" \
            width="324" \
            height="132" \
            autoplay="yes" loop="no" \
            target="rtsp://192.168.88.235:558/stream.sdp" />';
    var tdElementVIDEO4 = document.getElementById('TABLENAME');
    var trElementVIDEO4 = tdElementVIDEO4.parentNode;
    trElementVIDEO4.removeChild(tdElementVIDEO4);
    trElementVIDEO4.insertBefore(document.createRange().createContextualFragment(strVIDEO4),trElementVIDEO4.firstChild)

}
```

just use

```
trElementVIDEO4.insertBefore(document.createRange().createContextualFragment(strVIDEO4),trElementVIDEO4.firstChild)
```

instead of

```
trElementVIDEO4.innerHTML = strVIDEO4 + trElementVIDEO4.innerHTML;
```

in all ur scripts

also instead of placing click events in markup, keep them in javascript

instead of

```
<button style="background-color:green" type="button" onclick="display556VIDEO4()">6</button>-
<button style="background-color:green" type="button" onclick="display557VIDEO4()">7</button>-
<button style="background-color:green" type="button" onclick="display558VIDEO4()">8</button>-
<button style="background-color:green" type="button" onclick="display559VIDEO4()">9</button><br/>
```

use

```
 <button style="background-color:green" type="button" id= '556VIDEO4'>6</button>-
<button style="background-color:green" type="button" id= '557VIDEO4'>7</button>-
<button style="background-color:green" type="button" id= '558VIDEO4'>8</button>-
<button style="background-color:green" type="button" id= '559VIDEO4'>9</button><br/>
```

and in javascript place following code:

```
 document.addEventListener("click", function(e){
        if(e.target.tagName === 'BUTTON'){
        button = e.target;

        eval('display'+button.id+'()');//call display559VIDEO4()}
    });
```

Comment: Hmm... same problem. Worked once, never again.

Comment: That doesn't seem to fire off at all BUT it's shown me some ways to go about this. I will re-asses and get back. Thank you Shishir!

Comment: ok - none of the above is working. However, going back to my original code, if you remove the removeChild part i.e.: "trElementVIDEO4.removeChild(tdElementVIDEO4);", from each function then it actually DOES work - it just is not removing the old code and is stacking so when I remove the element, it's removing I think the ID and then getting lost?

Comment: NEW ISSUE: So while my issue has been resolved in swapping out the code properly, what breaks is Javascript elsewhere that MUTED the stream based on the id in the TD field. Even though looking in a debugger, the code is exactly the same if I press the same button as what stream is defaulted, it breaks the code and the script doesn't fire. - I looked in the debugger (Firefox) and all I can see is that offsetParent which WAS the correct ID (td#TABLEPEARL1) is now BLANK!! Not sure why or how to get that back but I think that's the issue...

Comment: Figured it out. Had to place declaration of variables inside the mute routine instead of outside where they were declared once and then lost when the code pop happened. Placing back into the mute routing reassigned them properly to the new injected code.

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

I need to include the `<TD id="TABLENAME">`and closing `</TD>` in the var str declarations! When it was swapping out, it was removing the TDs. Put them back in and original code works great.

Thanks for debugging help!